# Application gui gets loaded completely,but is visible only partially

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an issue when i run my android app in the emulator it opens fine all the contents are loaded..but when i run in my device it occupies only a part of the screen but the entire screen is loaded.its like when you change the resolution of your windows.the window just appears to be to big to fit in screen.please help me resolve this issue.

I tried uploading image but could not.but 
The layout defined is some thing like this

```
    <linearlayout(main layout)>
      <linearLayout>
         <TextView>xyz</TextView>
      </linearLayout>
      <linearLayout>
         <TextView>xyz</TextView>
      </linearLayout>
      <linearLayout>
         <TextView>xyz</TextView>
      </linearLayout>
     <TableLayout>
<TableRow>
         <TextView>xyz</TextView>
</TableRow>
      </TableLayout>
    </linearLayout(mainLayout)>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Layouts are not defined correctly. Check out the developer guides or post a more detailed problem.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html